# Cross-compiling nfs-utils package for Android

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, nfs

I would like to add NFS support (both client and server) for my Android device. I have already built and inserted the required kernel modules (`sunrpc.ko`, `lockd.ko`, `nfs.ko`, `exportfs.ko`, `nfsd.ko`)

My Android phone now can act as an NFS client by mounting using Busybox. But to work as an NFS server, seems like some utilities (such as `exportfs`) and service daemons (`portmap`, `nfsd`, `mountd`, etc) are missing.

I figured I needed to install the `nfs-utils` package (http://nfs.sourceforge.net/).

I thought I should cross-compile it on my pc and then install it on my phone's Linux kernel. I'm not familiar with the whole cross-compiling thing. I'm trying to compile it on Ubuntu right now, and this is the command I'm using:

```
$ ./configure 
  --target=arm-linux-gnueabi 
  --host=arm-linux-gnueabi 
  --build=x86_64-linux 
  CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
  CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/" 
  CFLAGS="-nostdlib" 
  LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/"
  LIBS="-lc"
```

This gives me the error msg:

> > *checking for libwrap... configure: error: *** libwrap missing*

config.log errors:

1. > *configure:3978: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -V >&5*
   >
   > *arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files*
2. > *configure:3978: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -qversion >&5*
   >
   > *arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files*
3. > *conftest.c:12:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory*
4. > *conftest.c:55:28: fatal error: sys/capability.h: No such file or directory*

I have the `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` package installed, but I guess there are some problems with building/linking with dependency libraries I don't really understand. Should they be cross-compiled too? How can I do that? And will I need to insert these libraries into my phone for NFS to run properly?

I'm completely new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency of tcp-wrappers which means you must first build and install tcp wrappers.

Alternatively, you can pass this option to ./configure:

--without-tcp-wrappers  \

Also, you can get a complete list of options:

./configure --help