# How to compile a kernel module file for Android

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, android-kernel

I'm trying to compile kernel module files for *Android*. The goal is then build `nfs-utils`, to get a *NFS* server working on my *Pixel 7* phone.

I downloaded the *AOSP* project and built a kernel:

```sh
$ mkdir android-kernel && cd android-kernel/
$ repo init --depth=1 --manifest-url=https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest --manifest-branch=android-gs-pantah-5.10-android13-qpr1
$ repo sync --current-branch --network-only --jobs=4
$ repo sync --current-branch --local-only --jobs=16
$ BUILD_CONFIG=aosp/build.config.gki.aarch64 build/build.sh
```

But how do I build a `.ko` file? I tried to build `exportfs.ko`, said to be required in [Cross-compiling nfs-utils package for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820670/cross-compiling-nfs-utils-package-for-android), but have no idea how to do it. (That question lists `sunrpc.ko`, `lockd.ko`, `nfs.ko`, `exportfs.ko`, `nfsd.ko`.)

After I built the kernel, `android-kernel/out/android13-5.10/dist/modules.builtin` suggests that it's bundled into the kernel.

I tried the following which produced no `.ko` files:

```sh
$ cd ~/android-kernel/out/android13-5.10/aosp/
$ make \
    ARCH=arm64 \
    CC=~/android-kernel/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r450784e/bin/clang \
    CROSS_COMPILE=~/android-kernel/aosp/scripts/dummy-tools/ \
    M=~/android-kernel/aosp/fs/exportfs \
    --directory=
    all
```

I googled around lots. It seems like most sources are rather old and don't make use of *AOSP*. Without *AOSP*, I tried to load my phone's kernel config in `/proc/config.gz` and use that to build, but this gives heaps of new build options that I must pick.

If modules can be built without *AOSP* that is acceptable too.

Comment: try this https://github.com/Drjacky/How-to-compile-kernel-module, use NDK

Comment: @k1r1t0 I'm having lots of trouble trying to follow that. Both *AOSP* and *NDK* only has *Clang* now. After trying to use *Clang* to build I get errors like ``aarch64-linux-android-ld: net/xdp/xsk_buff_pool.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external symbol `__stack_chk_guard' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC``. Honestly am quite stuck. I'd love to see a complete up-to-date method on how to build a kernel module.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you want to do with the NFS server? Is it an option to use an FTP server instead of NFS for example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a kernel mode NFS server you could run a user space NFS server. See [unfs3](https://github.com/unfs3/unfs3) on github.

This means you only have to cross-compile unfs3 (using the NDK) and not any kernel modules.